# Get page content that required authentication in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the content of page which required authentication (username and password ) , i can only access this page using valid username and password , i want to access this page using php library. can you please suggest a method or library using which i can access this page. Thanks .

Comment: 1/ where is your code so far ? 2/ what kind of auth the page you are trying to access uses ?

Comment: cURL can do it, stream contexts (`file_get_contents` and such) can do it, other libraries probably can, too. You could even use raw sockets for HTTP authentication. Do you have a specific question about implementing it?

Comment: Are you trying to make a request that requires HTTP basic or digest authentication?  If so, these are both possible using the built-in PHP curl library.

Comment: @camus its a scribd page login page (http://www.scribd.com/login) and i want to access this page (http://www.scribd.com/pro_stats/summary?start=2012-02-06&end=2012-03-06&granularity=day&norm=15) when access this page its shows redirection to login page

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
//CHANGE THIS
$username='YOUR_USERNAME';
$password='YOUR_PASSWORD';
$location='http://YOUR_ADDRESS/YOUR_FILE.php';


$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$location);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you narek , but this method is not working , it show page redirect to website login page

Comment: Sorry, this will work only for server authentication, not for custom.